# is briefly connecting same voltage/different capacity batteries safe

Tags: battery-charging, raspberry-pi, batteries

Ok, so I am working on a project that has two battery packs:

a: 7.4v 2Ah - 8 x 3.7v 500mAh

b: 7.4v 500mAh - 2 x 3.7v 500mAh

These packs will be powering a raspberry pi clone, a handful of servos, and possibly an arduino. I want to try a setup where the pi gracefully switches to the smaller pack when the larger pack is running low, switching the smaller one on while the larger is connected, then disconnecting the larger when the smaller is connected.

My question is: Is this "safe"? Meaning, is there anything I should worry about (spikes/oscillations/etc) by doing this? I've done some searching and can't find enough to make a call I can feel good with, only things regarding permanently having them connected.

I would like to do this so the build has some reserve power to make its way over to its charging station and send me a notification so I can plug it in. Maybe possibly running pi from low cap pack while the big one charges.

Should I refrain from having the two packs connected for a second or so? Any suggestions as to how to do this properly?

Edit: More relevant info about build

both of the packs are wired into a relay (separate channels) controlled by the pi, with a hard switch for the low cap batteries (as a main power switch), and from the relays into a power regulator/monitor, which provides the mains in the build. When the build needs to switch batteries, it disconnects the servo power supply before doing any switching so the only active load is the pi (and power monitor). 
Everything is hooked ready to go, but I havent plugged in the batteries because, well I dont know what will happen when the relay switches from low capacity (initial state) to the higher one.

Comment: AS you Packs have ESR so the load can affect the voltage and there are memory effects at low SoC and voltages may rise after the load is removed so choosing transfer voltage and hysteresis may be needed in your design spec.  The transfer time should be performed quickly to reduce additional loads of a weak battery.

Comment: going to add some more detail to the question about my build

Comment: With both packs charged to the exact same voltage, they can be connected without any problem. otherwise it could be risky.

Comment: the two packs are the same voltages,just different capacities. the packs are all made from the same 3.7v 500mAh cells. As far as the same voltages, I'm not sure how stable that would be as Im planning on having the pi run from the smaller pack while the larger one charges to avoid rebooting, thus  the lower one will be presumably almost empty when the smaller one kicks on. Is that an issue? Their LiPo batteries btw